# Some websites not accessible

Tags: mac

I am on a MacBook Pro, my wife has a PC. As of last night there are some websites we cannot access on either computer, including nearly all Apple websites, such as the App Store for updates and the support websites. Also none of our regular radio sites we listen to, and others. Some work all right. And it won't let me download Malwarebytes, though I got my wife to download it from work and email it to me (I installed and scanned; didn't solve the problem). I've deleted all my cookies, and changed to the google DNS. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try restarting your modem/router?

Answer (score 0):

If Google sites work but many/most non-Google sites don't, then you could have an MTU problem (maybe your ISP changed something on their network). Try setting your interface MTU down to something like 1300 and see if that fixes it. If it does, then try higher values until you find the highest value that works.

If it turns out to be an MTU problem, ask your ISP why full-size 1500-byte packets aren't working, and ask them why they have a Path MTU Discovery black hole on their network (Are they blocking ICMP "Destination Unreachable: Fragmentation required but 'don't fragment' bit set" messages?). Is your home gateway router provided by them? If so, ask them why it's not being told of the MTU limitation and/or why it's not smart enough to do MSS clamping.